# Tensorflow codart64_101.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have Tensorflow 2.3.1, Cuda 10.1 and v7.6.5.32 installend. The Path is also set and the File exist

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I still cannot use my GPU (GTX 1070) and getting the following error messages

```
2020-11-19 11:06:25.864932: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:25.865062: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-11-19 11:06:27.520315: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-11-19 11:06:27.539455: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.7715GHz coreCount: 15 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2020-11-19 11:06:27.539885: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:27.540206: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_10.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_10.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:27.540536: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:27.540820: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:27.541113: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:27.541396: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_10.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:27.541684: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
2020-11-19 11:06:27.541786: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follo
w the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I was using the Python version from the Windows Store. This version runs in a sandbox, therefore it cannot access the CUDA files, with the Python Version from the Python website it is working.